# Protractor When sendKeys meet issue 'cannot focus element'

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am not sure if Protractor can sendKeys to a div.

My code is

```
element(by.css('.create-api-schema-editor .CodeMirror .CodeMirror-lines .CodeMirror-code .CodeMirror-line')).sendKeys(content);
```

I also tried click first and then sendKeys, but no luck.

HTML is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUvZL.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried clicking specific co-ordinates and then using sendKeys. With your description, not sure if click is an issue or sendKey is an issue.

Comment: Click is working, I can see the focus is on that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue, we can use browser.actions().click().perform() instead of ele.click().

I am not sure why but it works.

Hope this helpful for you.